# Re-add the default top panel

Tags: gnome

I accidentally deleted the default **top panel** in ubuntu 10.04.

How can I **restore** it without completely re-building it one panel object at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See this post](http://www.starryhope.com/linux/ubuntu/2010/restore-the-default-panels-in-ubuntu/). It has step by step instructions as well as a well recorded video. He provides a script that can restore your top and bottom panels. Just in case you do it again :)

Comment: Thank you baby jesus! It worked. I was really starting to drive me crazy.

Comment: This worked beautifully the first time.

Answer (score 1):

[See this post](http://www.watchingthenet.com/restore-panels-in-ubuntu-back-to-their-default-settings.html). It will restore your panels back to their defaults. It doesn't discriminate in that any edits to your bottom panel will also be lost.

Open a terminal session by:
pressing Alt F2 > then type `gnome-terminal` > click on Run

Then enter the following code:

```
gconftool-2 –-recursive-unset /apps/panel # might be optional
rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/panel
pkill gnome-panel
```

Edit: Updated for gconftool-2

Comment: that post is very dated.

Comment: Tried it and it didn't work for me. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The only difference between the script and these three little commands is it needs to be `gconftool-2` instead of `gconftool`. I've edited my answer for other people so they don't have to download and run a script from a random place.

Comment: Oli: I tried it with gconftool-2 and it didn't work for me.

Comment: As I say, now this code is exactly the same as that in the script you say does work.

Comment: this post worked for me perfectly...thanks for your post Oli