# Restore panel in Ubuntu 14.04 gnome-session-fallback

Tags: gnome-panel, gnome-session-fallback

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 gnome. To make it more classic I installed the `gnome-session-fallback`. It worked fine, but accidentally I deleted the top panel. When I search for a solution, answers from Ubuntu 7-8 come up like this [Re-add the default top panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/889/re-add-the-default-top-panel)

However, it does not work for me as there is no ~/.gconf/apps/panel I believe this is because the panel is not native to the system, rather it is through `gnome-session-fallback`. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling `gnome-session-fallback`, but it did not work. I am trying to find the files that I can reset to get my top panel back to default.

Also, if it helps, the panel is fine if I log in as another user, so the setting files probably are in the home drive (I guess). Any ideas?

Comment: No other answers? I will appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out that the file containing information on panels etc. is `~/.config/dconf/user` So I just copied this file from another user and the panels are back to default ones.

Answer (score -1):

RUn the command:

```
gnome-panel --replace
```

`man gnome-panel`

```
DESCRIPTION
       The gnome-panel program provides the panels of the the GNOME desktop.

       The  panels  are  the  areas  on  the desktop that contain, among other
       items, the applications menu, application launchers,  the  notification
       area and the window list.

       Small  applications  called applets can also be embedded in the panels.
       The applets usually provide quick access to specific features.

OPTIONS
       --replace
              Replace an already running panel.
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Running that command gave me an error related to the executable gnome-panel. I'm lost. Any other ideas? I feel if I can delete the files that come with gnome-session-fallback and reinstall it, that should fix the issue. But what files I should delete, I am not sure.

Comment: please list down the error result from the command `gnome-panel --replace`

Comment: There are multiple errors: `(gnome-panel:10005): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.40.2/./gobject/gsignal.c:2462: signal 'size_request' is invalid for instance '0x28f7df0' of type 'GtkLabel'`,  `*** BUG ***In pixman_region32_init_rect: Invalid rectangle passed
Set a breakpoint on '_pixman_log_error' to debug` and once I got a segmentation fault and the panels completely disappeared.